# May a warm reset by pulling down the reset pin of the SoC cause the file system corrupts?

Tags: embedded, hardware, reset, nand-flash

In my embedded Linux system, I made a hardware switch to pull down the reset pin of the SoC(TI DM365). When the system is running, I can push the button to reboot the system. I want to know whether this behavior is safe to my file system or it will cause a corruption. I use Linux version 2.6.32 + jffs2 in my system. If yes,  can someone explain why the corruption happens? Very appreciated!

Is pulling down the reset pin as risky as cycling the power of the system which may causes the FS corrupts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, no. But that depends on the filesystem, and the the same rule apply as for a non-embedded system.

- read only fs will be ok
- journaling fs will at least remain internally consistent (to my understanding), but it's not clear if that is what you are actually asking.

Comment: Normally jffs2 should be stable under power loss, but look at http://lists.infradead.org/pipermail/linux-mtd/2011-May/035284.html - and depending on the level of reliability of your device, investigate it further.

Comment: See and follow up if power loss and hard reset are  the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30029659/why-file-in-jffs2-gets-corrupted-after-power-loss-during-removal-of-other-files